# How does Gatsby application access Azure Key Vault

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, azure-keyvault, azure-static-web-app

I have sucessfully deployed my Gatsby App to Azure as per these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/publish-gatsby). This is a separate resource from a "normal" web app. The "normal web app would be deployed to the App Service resource but for Gatsby it is deployed to a different Static Web Page Reqource. So the URL now has the form https://<generated name>.azurestaticapps.net where the generated-name is NOT the application name. So it seems that the instructions for hooking the web service up with the key vault have some holes to be filled in. What are the steps that I need to take to connect my Gatsby App to my azure key vault during development and on the production site?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node

Comment: The problem that I am having with this documentation is that I seem to be running into a TypeScript issue. My secret is a string. I am not clear on how to get this 'string' from the KeyVaultSecret.

Comment: Also I have code setup like       get GoogleMapApiKey() {
        return (async () => await this.keyVaultClient.getSecret('GoogleMapApiKey'));
    }
Which as I understand it would return a KeyVaultSecret when the promise is resolved. Unfortunately it seems that the promise never seems to be resolved?

Comment: I notice that when setting up the secret client I get an error:

This error have something to do with it? Error: EnvironmentCredential is not supported in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: EnvironmentCredential is not supported in the browser.

In your case, use `ClientSecretCredential` instead of others.

Make sure you have done the [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-node#prerequisites), then in your code, use [`ClientSecretCredential`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity/v/1.0.3#authenticating-as-a-service-principal), pass the `tenantId, clientId, clientSecret` of your service principal to it, it should be something like below, `retrievedSecret.value` is the value of the secret.

```
const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");

const keyVaultName = "xxxx";
const KVUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";

const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
const client = new SecretClient(KVUri, credential);

const retrievedSecret = await client.getSecret(secretName);
```

Comment: Thank you. You have been most helpful. Using TypeScript I have ```
         const mapsKey:KeyVaultSecret = await keyVault.GoogleMapApiKey;
        setGoogleMapsApiKey(mapsKey.value ?? '' );
```
and get 
```
Property 'properties' is missing in type '() => Promise<KeyVaultSecret>' but required in type 'KeyVaultSecret'.ts(2741)
keyvault-secrets.d.ts(101, 5): 'properties' is declared here.
```

Comment: I know this is not intended to be a discussion but after "resolving" the Promise issue I now get a console error that seems to point me to a CORS issue but I don't seem to have any control over the request?
```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://greatstatekeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/GoogleMapApiKey/?api-version=7.1' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Further down the stack I see what my be the root cause:
```
{
"error": {
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Request is missing a Bearer or PoP token."
}
}
```

Comment: @KevinBurton Related to this issue, I recommend you to ask it in a new question, including the code and error, it will be clear to others.